# What is the difference between average sperm epimutations and intersection sperm epimutations, in the context of the attached article?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, evolution, dna, molecular-genetics

The paper of interest is [Manikkam et al. (2014)](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0102091).

In research for a school Year 10 Science project, I came upon this article and the following two graphics. I don’t quite understand the difference between the two graphics in the context of the article: what is the difference between average and insertion epimutations? Also, what do the Mb’s along the x-axis mean? Is it in a reference to genetic information size, like megabytes? And how does it refer to the loci of the epigenetic changes? I want to be able to interpret and explain this graph, so could someone provide an analysis and explanation of these graphics.

[image]
[image]

Comment: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0102091

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. I added the link in the post. It has no good reason to be in a comment. Maybe you did not know how to add a link in a post.

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn’t let me add more than 2 links to a page, and I think the images counted as links.

Comment: Oh indeed [users with less than 10 points of reputations are limited to two links apparently](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23386/number-of-links-in-the-question). I'm not sure why this restriction though!